# LARAVEL 7: Update user profile in laravel 7 based on the user who logs into the website

Tags: php, user-controls, laravel-7, profile

I have created a controller, model and view for the Profile menu, but when I try to update my own profile, the data cannot be updated and the ERROR message is not found.

this is the ProfileController.php file:

```
enter code here

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Profile;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

public function edit($id)
{
    return view('profile.profile',compact('id'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $profile = Profile::find($id)->first();

    $this->validate($request, [
        "name"     => 'required|string',
        "email"    => 'required|email|unique:users',
        "alamat"   => 'required',
        "nohp"     => 'required',
        "password" => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
    ]);

    if ($request->has('password')){
        $profile->name    = $request->name;
        $profile->email   = $request->email;
        $profile->alamat  = $request->alamat;
        $profile->nohp    = $request->nohp;
        $profile->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    }
    else{
        $profile->name    = $request->name;
        $profile->email   = $request->email;
        $profile->alamat  = $request->alamat;
        $profile->nohp    = $request->nohp;
    }

    $profile->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

this is the profile.php file:

```
enter code here
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container bg-white">
  <!-- Content Header -->
  <div class="content-header">
    <!-- CARD PROFILE -->
    <section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card card-warning" style="border-top-left-radius:40px; border-top-right-radius:40px;">
              <div class="card-body box-profile" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <img src="{{asset('adminlte/dist/img/user.png')}}" class="img-circle elevation-2" style="width:140px; height: 140px; margin-left: 85px; margin-bottom: 10px;" alt="User Image" align="center">
                <h3 align="center"><strong>{{Auth::user()->name}}</strong></h3>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card card-warning" style="margin-top: 15px; border-radius:40px;">
              <div class="card-header" style="background-image: linear-gradient(#40E0D0,#40E0D0);">
                <h4 class="card-tittle" align="center"><strong>Tentang Saya</strong></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body" style="font-family:glacial-indiference;">
                <strong><img src="{{asset('adminlte/dist/img/email.png')}}" style="width:30px; height: 30px; margin-left: 7px; margin-right: 4px"
                > Email</strong>
                <p class="text-muted" style="margin-left: 45px">{{Auth::user()->email}}</p>
                <hr>

                <strong><img src="{{asset('adminlte/dist/img/address.png')}}" style="width:30px; height: 30px; margin-left: 7px; margin-right: 4px"
                > Alamat</strong>
                <p class="text-muted" style="margin-left: 45px">{{Auth::user()->alamat}}</p>
                <hr>

                <strong><img src="{{asset('adminlte/dist/img/phone.png')}}" style="width:30px; height: 30px; margin-left: 6px; margin-right: 6px"
                > No. Telp</strong>
                <p class="text-muted" style="margin-left: 45px">{{Auth::user()->nohp}}</p>
                <hr>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card col-md-12" style="border-top-right-radius:40px; border-bottom-left-radius:40px;">
              <h4 class="card-tittle" align="center" style="margin-top:20px">
                <strong>Edit Profile</strong>
              </h4>
              <form action="{{ route('profile.profile', $id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:95%; margin-left:16px"> @method('patch')
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Nama</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"  value="{{Auth::user()->email}}" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="alamat">Alamat</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="alamat"  value="{{Auth::user()->alamat}}" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nohp">NoHP</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="nohp"  value="{{Auth::user()->nohp}}" required>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                            <label>*) Jika Password tidak diganti, kosongkan saja.</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" align="center" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block" style=" border-radius:30px; background-image: linear-gradient(#40E0D0,#40E0D0); width:60%; height:20%"
                          >Perbaharui</button> 
                      </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
</div>
@endsection

enter code here
```

when run, the result will be like this:
[data before updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crtuK.png)

the data after being replaced and the results are back as before:
[the data after being replaced and the results are back as before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3jOj.png)

I don't know where the error is because there is no ERROR message.
I need your help to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the record you are trying to find by 'id'. `Profile::find($id)->first();` is finding the record with the primary key `$id` and then doing a new query to get the "first" record from the table. So `$profile` is not the record you are trying to find by 'id'; you are updating the wrong record (the same wrong record) every time.

```
$profile = Profile::findOrFail($id);
```

We will use `findOrFail` to not have to deal with any `null` being returned if it can't find a record.

On a side note, the `if/else` could use some cleaning:

```
if ($request->has('password')) {
    $profile->password = bcrypt($request->password);
}

$profile->name = $request->name;
...
```